# Android install-time asset delivery can't access the asset folder

Tags: android, assets

I followed this guide [Integrate asset delivery (Kotlin & Java)](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java) from step 1-8, to integrate install-time asset delivery. I added folders with drawables to my \asset_pack1\src\main\assets folder, but i can't access them with code or open the folder in android studio. When i build my bundle with gradle, the manifest appers in asset_pack1\build\intermediates\asset_pack_manifest, but the drawable folders don't.

[it doesn't show the content of asset_pack1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDemn.png)

I've create the build.gradle in my asset_pack1 folder:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.asset-pack'
}

assetPack {
    packName = "asset_pack1"
    dynamicDelivery {
        deliveryType = "install-time"
    }
}
```

Setuo the asset pack in my app build.gradle:

```
android {
..
 assetPacks = [":asset_pack1"]
..
}
```

Included the pack in my settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':asset_pack1'
```

Added my asset directories:
[Content of \asset_pack1\src\main\assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8OgZ.png)

And built the bundle with gradle:

[over the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vt4y.png)

Also tried it over the terminal with: ./gradlew bundle

Does anyone know what i did wrong?

I followed the guide multiple times but always with the same result. Could't find any thread describing the same problem.

Comment: Did you manage this problem?

Comment: No, I stopped trying for now. But I will need asset delivery in future at some point. Only idea i have at the moment would be testing If it works in a new Project.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see the contents of the folder, you are probably in the [Android View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACnXd.png) of the project as opposed to the [Project View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHklQ.png).

It's the 'Project' view, that allows you to see the content of the asset packs. Simply press the drop down and select the desired view.